# wp_verify_nonce fails always

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, security, nonce

I have created nonce fro my plugin and trying to verify it with another plugin pages. it fails always. both we are creating nonce with same parameter. why it fails.
Plugin name : Wordfence
it creates nonce with `wp_create_nonce('wp-ajax')` i'm also doing the same. why it fails.
they are passing it via $_GET and accessing it. why i cannot i'm also passing the via $GET.

any idea about it. they are creating in different file and verifying it in a different file. i'm also creating in my plugin file and trying to verify in their file.

What they are doing in menu.php.

they have a link with following code and finally creates nonce with `wp-ajax`

```
href="<?php echo wfUtils::siteURLRelative(); ?>?_wfsf=conntest&nonce=<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'wp-ajax' ); ?>"
```

and checking in another file

```
$nonce = $_GET['nonce'];
if(! wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'wp-ajax')){
  echo "Bad security token.";
  exit(0);
}
showSummary();
```

and i do the same thing

```
<?php echo $directPath; echo wp_create_nonce( 'wp-ajax' ); ?>"
```

when i click this link it goes to that page and `$nonce = $_GET['nonce'];` i can see the data in $nonce. but verifying end in fail

Comment: other than telling you you're doing something wrong, we can't answer your question without seeing any code.

Comment: @Milo any idea , i have added the code

Comment: There's a lot of context missing here. I'm not sure why you're creating a nonce with the same action that another plugin is using.

Comment: because i want to show the summary from my plugin of them. once nonce gets verified then i can get summary

Comment: what's the context of where you create and verify the nonce? what action do you do both on? have you tried creating your own unique nonce action?